# How to add extra arguments/parameters to ajax callback function?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I am using drupal 7. I need to add extra arguments to my ajax callback function. I have five fieldsets in my form, and in all of them same there are same elements, just their IDs are different. For example; `group-1`, `group-2`... I need to include that `1,2,3..` part in the callback function as arguments. Otherwise, it will be too complicated to build a logic to predict which fieldset element need to change.

For example, is such a an implementation possible?

```
function mymodule_form($form, $form_state) {
    $group = 1;

    // Some form elements...

    $form['button'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'my_callback_function',
            'wrapper' => 'my_target_area',
            'arguments' => array($group1, ...) // Is such a thing possible or another way? 
        ),
    );
}

function my_callback_function($args, $form, $form_state) {
    $arguments = $args;
    return $form['my_target_area'];
}
```

This question as already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088455/pass-arguments-to-ajax-callback-function-in-drupal-7-form-api). But I those answers don't fit my needs mentioned above. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Drupal doesn't have a mechanism to do that, no. As mentioned in the post you linked to, there's no need to pass that data to Javascript and then back to PHP though - just keep it in the form:

```
function mymodule_form($form, $form_state) {
  $form['button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'my_callback_function',
      'wrapper' => 'my_target_area',
    ),
  );

  $form['#foo'] = array($group1, ...);

}

function my_callback_function($form, $form_state) {
  $arguments = $form['#foo'];
  return $form['my_target_area'];
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, pass the $form array to my callback function. From this code it appears the arguments are available, but the $form argument appears empty when the callback is called. `function my_ajax_cb($form, $form_state) {
  dpm($form);`

Answer (score 6):

For pass data to ajaxCallback, this is how i do :

```
$form['repas'][$i]['detail']['midi']['mois_midi_'.$i] = [
              '#type' => 'select',
              '#title' => $this->t('Mois'),
              '#data'=>$i,
              '#options'=>array(
                  ''=>'Tous',
                  '01'=>'Janvier',
                  '02'=>'Février',
                  '03'=>'Mars',
                  '04'=>'Avril',
                  '05'=>'Mai',
                  '06'=>'Juin',
                  '07'=>'Juillet',
                  '08'=>'Aout',
                  '09'=>'Septembre',
                  '10'=>'Octobre',
                  '11'=>'Novembre',
                  '12'=>'Décembre',

              ),
              '#ajax'   => [
                  'event' => 'change',
                  'effet'=>'fade',
                  'wrapper'=>'legumes'.$i,
                  'method'=>'replace',
                  'callback' => array($this,'changeLegumeCallback'),
              ],
              '#default_value'=>$mois,
          ];
```

> i add a custom attributes to my array : #data

Then in the callback :

```
public function changeLegumeCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    echo $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#data'];
    exit();

}
```

You ll get your dynamic value from the trigger Element.

Comment: For me it ended up being `$i = $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#field_parents'][1]` for node form field.

Answer (score 0):

```
$form["action"] = [
  "#type" => "button",
  "#value" => "Retirer",
  "#arg" => $id,
  "#attributes" => ["class" => ["button button--small"]],
  "#ajax" => [
    "callback" => [$this,"remove_chiffre_item"],
    "event" => "click",   
    "progress" => [],
  ],
];

public function remove_chiffre_item(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $element= $form_state->getTriggeringElement()["#arg"]; // $form["action"]["#arg"]
  drupal_set_message($element);
  return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

an other solution (I had to loop on inputs) :

```
$form['propositions_fieldset'][$i]['add_date_de_pose'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => t('Ajouter une date de pose'),
'#submit' => array('ajax_date_de_pose_add_more_add_one'),
'#name'=>$i,
  '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_date_de_pose_add_more_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'date-de-pose-fieldset-wrapper-'.$i,
     ),
);
```

You just have to add your argument with #name => $i

And get it back into the callback function with :

```
$i = $form_state['clicked_button']['#name'];


function ajax_date_de_pose_add_more_callback($form, $form_state) {
    $i = $form_state['clicked_button']['#name'];
    return $form['propositions_fieldset'][$i]['dates_de_pose_fieldset'];
}
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Put this code into a trait

```
/**
   * Callback to trigger evolution of the number of text field.
   */
  public function addMoreCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $triggerElement = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
    if (empty($targetElement = $triggerElement['#ajax']['target'])) {
      return [];
    }
    return $form[$targetElement] ?? [];
  }

  /**
   * Submit handler for the "add-one-more" button.
   *
   * Increments the max counter and causes a rebuild.
   */
  public function addOne(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state): void {
    $triggerElement = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
    if (empty($counter = $triggerElement['#ajax']['counter'])) {
      return;
    }
    $counterValue = $form_state->get($counter);
    $form_state->set($counter, $counterValue + 1);
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }

  /**
   * Submit handler for the "remove one" button.
   *
   * Decrements the max counter and causes a form rebuild.
   */
  public function removeCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state): void {
    $triggerElement = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
    if (empty($counter = $triggerElement['#ajax']['counter'])) {
      return;
    }
    $counterValue = $form_state->get($counter);
    if ($counterValue > 1) {
      $form_state->set($counter, $counterValue - 1);
    }
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }

  /**
   * Add textfield with add more button.
   *
   * @param array $form
   *   Form concern.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *   Form state object.
   * @param string $field
   *   Field name.
   */
  protected function addMultipleTextField(array &$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state, string $field): void {
    $counter = $field . '_count';
    $counterValue = $form_state->get($counter) ?? 1;
    $form_state->set($counter, $counterValue);

    $wrapperId = $field . '_wrapper';
    $fieldset = $field . '_fieldset';
    $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
    $form[$fieldset] = [
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $this->t($field . '_label'),
      '#prefix' => '<div id="' . $wrapperId . '">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $counterValue; $i++) {
      $form[$fieldset][$field][$i] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
      ];
    }

    $form[$fieldset]['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'actions',
    ];
    $form[$fieldset]['actions']['add_name'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('@add_more_' . $field),
      '#submit' => [[$this, 'addOne']],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'addMoreCallback'],
        'wrapper' => $wrapperId,
        'target' => $fieldset,
        'counter' => $counter,
      ],
    ];
    // If there is more than one name, add the remove button.
    if ($counterValue > 1) {
      $form[$fieldset]['actions']['remove_name'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Remove one'),
        '#submit' => [[$this, 'removeCallback']],
        '#ajax' => [
          'callback' => [$this, 'addMoreCallback'],
          'wrapper' => $wrapperId,
          'target' => $fieldset,
          'counter' => $counter,
        ],
      ];
    }
  }
```

Then, in your form, just call that

```
    $this->addMultipleTextField($form, $form_state, 'my_field');
```

And enyoy