# How do I call php functions with parameters from Js in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8

I am attempting to create/read nodes from a JS file (the nodes are created in response to Js events from a library). The PHP functions to create/read the nodes have been created and require field data as parameters. How can I run these functions from a JS file and pass the required data as parameters? I am willing to relocate/rewrite the functions in a new PHP file if required.

- I cannot use routing/controllers/API endpoints as I would need to pass parameters as slugs - some parameters are strings and may contain slashes which are not supported by routing
- The generation and submission of data is based on a JS library rather than Drupal forms, so I cannot use Drupal Ajax forms and pass my parameters through that. Without forms, Ajax callbacks have no [support for parameters](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/180570/how-to-add-extra-arguments-parameters-to-ajax-callback-function).
- I am not sure if [this Ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757750/how-can-i-call-php-functions-by-javascript/15758129#15758129) is an option with Drupal - if it is, how would I structure the 'url' in the Ajax request to get a certain php file from my module?

Comment: It seems like everything is pointing to you wanting to do this outside of Drupal - at which point it’s just php and Ajax right? With the php file bootstrapping Drupal so you can access nodes?

Comment: Thank you Clive, that seems like the best option at this point. If I add a new php file to my module, do you know how I would be able to refer to that file from js (i.e my third point in the post)?

Comment: Found it, thank you very much for your help